# How to show that every $A ∈ L(V)$ has a unique decomposition as a sum of a symmetric and an antisymmetric operator?

Tags: vector-spaces

I need to show that every $A ∈ L(V)$ has a unique decomposition as a sum of a symmetric and an antisymmetric operator, where $V$ be an Euclidean vector space with scalar product $(.|.)$.

A linear map $A ∈ L(V)$ is said to be symmetric (real-self-adjoint), if
$$A^T = A,$$
it is said to be antisymmetric (scew-symmetric), if
$$A^T = −A.$$

What if I represent $A$ as $\dfrac {A+A^T}{2}+\dfrac {A-A^T}{2}$?

Comment: Exactly: you answered your own question. Nice. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already wrote $A$ as a sum of symmetric and anti-symmetric operator so you answered the existence question. Now assume that you can write

$$A= S+M=S'+M'$$
where $S$ and $S'$ are symmetric and $M$ and $M'$ are anti-symmetric so
$$S-S'=M'-M\implies S=S'\;\text{and}\; M=M'\quad \text{why ?}$$

Comment: I don't know. Please hint me.

Comment: $S-S'$ is symmetric and $M'-M$ is anti-symmetric so if they are equal so we get a matrix which's at the same time symmetric and anti-symmetric. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh... It's a zero matrix, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it's the only symmetric and anti-symmetric matrix.